# Spherical equation with Laplace Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a question about my approach to [another question asked here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314249/solve-the-following-pde-using-fourier-transform)

$$u_{tt}=C^2[u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}],\qquad-\infty<x,y,z<\infty,\qquad t>0$$ $$BC: u(x,y,z,t)\rightarrow 0\qquad as \qquad r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2\rightarrow \infty \qquad $$ $$IC: u(x,y,z,0)=f(r),\qquad  r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} , \qquad u_t(x,y,z,0)=0 $$

Since there is radial symmetry I use the radial component of the laplacian:

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\bigg)$$

I laplace transform the time. Also $U'=\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}$

$$s^2U-s f(r)=c^2U''+\frac{2c^2}{r}U'$$

$$U''+\frac{2}{r}U'-\frac{s^2}{c^2}U=-sf(r)$$

The homogeneous solution (because I can't solve for a function I do not know) to this equation is

$${exp\bigg({\pm\frac{s}{c}r}}\bigg)\rightarrow \frac{\delta(t\pm \frac rc)}{r}$$

Which has some resemblance of a correct solution (time convolution with any function takes the correct form) because the general solution should look like

$$\frac{f(t\pm \frac rc)}{r}$$

What am I missing, which step am I skipping, doing wrong?

Comment: Have you learned about Green's Functions?

Comment: @Dr.MV I haven't even learned about PDE's, I was just curious.

Comment: The problem is missing a boundary condition, say at $r=0$.